# NGINX + PHP-FPM7.2 502 Error include large file

Tags: php, apache, docker, nginx

Runnigg simple php script nginx+php-fpm7.2

index.php:

```
echo "start";
include ('/var/www/public/test.php');
echo "end";
```

test.php :

```
$a['components/xxxx/yyyy1/.description.php'] = 1;    
$a['components/xxxx/yyyy2/.description.php'] = 1;    
$a['components/xxxx/yyyy3/.description.php'] = 1;  
$a['components/xxxx/yyyy4/.description.php'] = 1;    
$a['components/xxxx/yyyy5/.description.php'] = 1;  
.......
.......
$a['components/xxxx/yyyy80000/.description.php'] = 1;
```

60000 lines - work well

80000 lines (6,8 MB) - run time 2sec and nginx error 502

> 2018/06/27 08:11:12 [error] 6#6: *6 recv() failed (104: Connection
>   reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   172.20.0.1, server: test, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "172.20.0.6"

How to solve this problem?